# Does any cloud object stores support object metadata indices?

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, key-value-store, nosql

I have a very large document store - about 50 million JSON docs, with 50m more added per year.  Each is about 10K.  I would like to store them in a cloud storage and retrieve them via a couple structured metadata indices that I would update as I add documents to the store.

It looks like AWS S3, Google Cloud Storage and Azure allow custom metadata to be returned with an object, but not used as part of a GET request to filter a collection of objects.

Is there a good solution "out-of-the-box" for this?  I can't find any, but it seems like my use case shouldn't be really unusual.  I don't need to query by document attributes or to return partial documents, I just need to GET a collection of documents by filtering on a handful of metadata fields.

The [AWS SimpleDB page](http://aws.amazon.com/simpledb/) mentions "Indexing Amazon S3 Object Metadata" as a use case, and links to [a library](http://aws.amazon.com/code/1465?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1) that hasn't been updated since 2009.

Answer (score 0):

They are simply saying that you can store and query the metadata in amazon simple DB which is a NoSQL database provided by amazon for you. Depending on the kind of metadata you have, you could also store it in an RDBMS. Few 100 million rows isn’t too much if you create the proper indices and you can store URLs or file names, to access the files stored on S3, Azure, … afterwards.